# How do you read all but the last 2 lines of a file in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have a large number of input files that I want to read. They contain a varying number of total lines. I want to read all the lines up to the last two lines in each file. How do I do this? Is the only way to count first the number of lines in each file and then read the desired number of lines? Or is there something much more efficient than something like the following?

```
   DO I = 1,1000

      OPEN(UNIT=I,FILE=FILENAME,STATUS='UNKNOWN',ACTION='READ')

      DO
         READ(I,*,IOSTAT=IO)
         IF (IO/=0) EXIT
         nlines(I) = nlines(I) + 1
      END DO

      REWIND(I)

      DO J = 1,nlines(I)-2
         READ(I,*) A(J)
      END DO

   END DO
```

Comment: Welcome. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention. You can add a tag for specific version to version-specific questions, bout your question is not version-specific.

Comment: Read 3 lines into 3 buffers.  Process the line in buffer 1.  Promote the contents of buffer 2 to buffer 1, 3 to 2, try to read another line into buffer 3.  If you haven't reached the end of the file, process the line in buffer 1.  If you have, ignore the lines in buffers 2 and 3 and get on with the rest of the program.  You could use indexes or pointers instead of moving lines from buffer to buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just ignoring the last two lines (i.e. simply decrementing nlines(i) by 2 after reading is done) ?
I.e.:

```
 DO I = 1,1000

  OPEN(UNIT=I,FILE=FILENAME,STATUS='UNKNOWN',ACTION='READ')

  DO J=1, size(A)
     READ(I,*,IOSTAT=IO) A(J)
     IF (IO/=0) EXIT
  END DO
  nlines(I) = J-3   ! 3 not 2 because J is already incremented 

END DO
```